# Is there a way to get game data back on a PS Vita?

Tags: ps-vita

The question pretty much says it: Is it possible to retrieve lost game data after it's corrupted?

My memory card came out an two years of game data was lost... so yeah.

Comment: I don't suppose you have backups (on PS3 or PC), or PS Plus Cloud saves?

Comment: Nope. That's why I asked.

Comment: Have the save files themselves become corrupted? is the whole game installation corrupt? or is the whole memory card corrupt? if you are not sure of the answer to the above then can you describe what happens when you try and load a save file in question.

Comment: Okay. I turned my Vita on and all the games were completely gone (the games were downloaded). And data is saved to games, so...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what files have actually become corrupt you have some options but no guarantees that you will get ***any*** data back.

The first thing to try is to ***Rebuild your PS Vita database.***

---

This can be done directly from the Vita itself, to do this you first have to start the Vita in recovery mode, then select the rebuild data base option form the menu, see step by step instructions and picture below:

- Turn the Vita off (hold down power button)
- Now press and hold “R” (Right on D-Pad) + Power button + PS (PlayStation Button)
- The Vita will start in 'Recovery Mode'
- Select option '2.Rebuild Database'
- This could take a while so make sure your Vita is plugged in to a power source.

You can also try the option '4.Restore the Vita System' but this is not likely to fix corrupted game data. Neither of these options will delete any save files.

[image: recovery mode menu]

---

You could also try and use a PC to ***run data recovery software on the memory card***

To do this you will need data recovery software installed on your PC, you may have to purchase this software. (This is not something I have done personally so I can't make any recommendations.) To do this you will need a basic level of computer knowledge to follow the generic instruction below:

- Download/install recovery software (if not already installed),
- Connect the PS vita memory card to your PC either thorough the Vita itself or with an adapter,
- run recovery software on the memory card and follow software specific instructions, this should extract all recovered files on to your PC,
- Find the save files and restore them to the memory card.

---

***Hopefully now you have learned to back up "important" files!***